# Cant create typescript + react module

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, typescript

Trying to create react component with typescript inside ASP.NET 5 app.
Thats code is okay:

```
class AppRoot extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>test</div>
        );
    }
}
```

but thats is not okay:

```
module Pages {

export class AppRoot extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>test</div>
        );
    }
}

}
```

Error:

```
ScriptEngineException: Error: ../Scripts/Pages/AppRoot.tsx: Unexpected     token (5:7)
3 | ///// <reference path="./interfaces.d.ts"/>
4 | 
> 5 | module Pages {
| ^
6 |
```

Whats wrong with him, guys? =| 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> module Pages {

This should have been *compiled away*. i.e. the runtime JavaScript should not contain `*module*`. Perhaps you forgot to compile the TypeScript to JavaScript.